# My custom C++ plugin is not being consumed by the qml test application

Tags: qt, plugins, qml, qtplugin

I am new to Qt and learning few of the modules in Qt-Qml from youtube and Qt documentation. I want to create cpp plugin which is to be consumed by the qml application.

For this, I have created two projects. One is for creating a plugin library and another application is for consuming the plugin.

I am able to create the plugin library successfully. But, not able to consume it by the test application.

The test application is compiled successfully but throwing below error during run time.

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
> qrc:/main.qml:3:1: module "MyPlugin" is not installed

I have read the Qt documentation and googled a lot, but could not able to resolve it.

- Qt : 5.15.7
- Qt Creator: 5.0.3
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

**Project 1:** Creating Plugin library

CreatePlugin.pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = CreatePlugin
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += plugin c++11

DESTDIR = ../pluginFiles
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = MyPlugin

# Input
SOURCES += \
createplugin_plugin.cpp \
myplugin.cpp

HEADERS += \
createplugin_plugin.h \
myplugin.h

DISTFILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) "$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)" 
"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)"
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
   PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}

# Copy the qmldir file to the same folder as the plugin binary
cpqmldir.files = qmldir
cpqmldir.path = $$DESTDIR
COPIES += cpqmldir
```

createplugin_plugin.h

```
#ifndef CREATEPLUGIN_PLUGIN_H
#define CREATEPLUGIN_PLUGIN_H

#include <QQmlExtensionPlugin>

class CreatePluginPlugin : public QQmlExtensionPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID QQmlExtensionInterface_iid)

public:
    void registerTypes(const char *uri) override;
};

#endif // CREATEPLUGIN_PLUGIN_H
```

createplugin_plugin.cpp

```
#include "createplugin_plugin.h"

#include "myplugin.h"

#include <qqml.h>

void CreatePluginPlugin::registerTypes(const char *uri)
{
    // @uri MyPlugin
    qmlRegisterType<MyPlugin>(uri, 1, 0, "MyPlugin");
}
```

myplugin.h

```
#ifndef MYPLUGIN_H
#define MYPLUGIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class MyPlugin : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyPlugin)

public:
    explicit MyPlugin(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyPlugin() override;

public slots:
    QString getString();
};
#endif // MYPLUGIN_H
```

myplugin.cpp

```
#include "myplugin.h"

MyPlugin::MyPlugin(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    // By default, QQuickItem does not draw anything. If you subclass
    // QQuickItem to create a visual item, you will need to uncomment the
    // following line and re-implement updatePaintNode()

    // setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);
}

MyPlugin::~MyPlugin()
{
}

QString MyPlugin::getString()
{
    return "This is CPP String";
}
```

qmldir

```
module MyPlugin
plugin CreatePlugin
```

**Project 2:** TestPlugin

TestPlugin.pro

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before 
Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    #endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                 &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import MyPlugin 1.0 

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyPlugin {
        id: mypluginId
    }

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(mypluginId.getString())
}
```